# False indentation after line continuation in if-else clause for `sh` filetype

Tags: indentation, shell

I have shell script file (`filetype=sh`) like

```
if [ -f filename ]; then
    echo "file exit" | \
        cat -
else
    echo "file not exist"
fi
```

When I select the block and apply indent ( by `{Visual}=` ),
then it becomes

```
if [ -f filename ]; then
    echo "file exit" | \
        cat -
        else
            echo "file not exist"
fi
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I’m not sure there’s a good way to. The shell indenter often gets confused by continuation lines, in my experience.